# Convert string to decimal number with 2 decimal places in Java

Tags: java, string, floating-point, number-formatting

In Java, I am trying to parse a string of format `"###.##"` to a float.  The string should always have 2 decimal places.

Even if the String has value `123.00`, the float should also be `123.00`, not `123.0`.

This is what I have so far:

```
System.out.println("string liters of petrol putting in preferences is " + stringLitersOfPetrol);

Float litersOfPetrol = Float.parseFloat(stringLitersOfPetrol);

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

litersOfPetrol = Float.parseFloat(df.format(litersOfPetrol));

System.out.println("liters of petrol before putting in editor: " + litersOfPetrol);
```

It prints:

```
string liters of petrol putting in preferences is 010.00 
liters of petrol before putting in editor: 10.0
```

Comment: dont parse the formatted string again maybe?

Comment: `setMinimumFractionDigits` sounds more appropriate.

Comment: don't parse to a float

Comment: That can't be done using float and double. BigDecimal can do that.

Comment: if it is not possible to do using float or double, is there any other way to retain 2 decimal places with which the incoming string is coming?

Comment: It _is_ possible as many answers suggest: just use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
litersOfPetrol = Float.parseFloat(df.format(litersOfPetrol));
```

There you formatted your float to string as you wanted, but but then that string got transformed again to a float, and then what you printed in stdout was  your float that got a standard formatting. Take a look at this code

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

String stringLitersOfPetrol = "123.00";
System.out.println("string liters of petrol putting in preferences is "+stringLitersOfPetrol);
Float litersOfPetrol=Float.parseFloat(stringLitersOfPetrol);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
stringLitersOfPetrol = df.format(litersOfPetrol);
System.out.println("liters of petrol before putting in editor : "+stringLitersOfPetrol);
```

And by the way, when you want to use decimals, forget the existence of double and float as others suggested and just use BigDecimal object, it will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Thanks ! I got it ! And now I am using  java.lang.BigDecimal instead of float

Comment: Why Double.parsedouble("2.30") returns 2.3? and not 2.30?

Comment: Is it not the same?

Answer (score 20):

**Java convert a String to decimal:**

```
String dennis = "0.00000008880000";
double f = Double.parseDouble(dennis);
System.out.println(f);
System.out.println(String.format("%.7f", f));
System.out.println(String.format("%.9f", new BigDecimal(f)));
System.out.println(String.format("%.35f", new BigDecimal(f)));
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", new BigDecimal(f)));
```

This prints:

```
8.88E-8
0.0000001
0.000000089
0.00000008880000000000000106383001366
0.00
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `BigDecimal`:

```
new BigDecimal(theInputString);
```

It retains all decimal digits. And you are sure of the exact representation since it uses decimal base, not binary base, to store the precision/scale/etc.

And it is not subject to precision loss like `float` or `double` are, unless you explicitly ask it to.

Comment: I doubt that with two decimal places, precision loss is an issue

Comment: I know, but if you deal only with two decimal places, this will never be a problem. Even Intels are not that inaccurate.

Comment: @Arian even with "only" two decimal places, as you say, this is a problem. Since IEEE 754 does NOT talk in decimal to begin with, but in binary.

Comment: Why Double.parsedouble("2.30") returns 2.3? and not 2.30?

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to be sure that the float number will also have 2 decimal places after converting that string.

You can't, because floating point numbers don't *have* decimal places. They have *binary* places, which aren't commensurate with decimal places.

If you want decimal places, use a decimal radix.

Answer (score 2):

```
litersOfPetrol = Float.parseFloat(df.format(litersOfPetrol));

System.out.println("liters of petrol before putting in editor : "+litersOfPetrol);
```

You print `Float here`, that has no format at all.

To print formatted float, just use

```
String formatted = df.format(litersOfPetrol);
System.out.println("liters of petrol before putting in editor : " + formatted);
```

Comment: Why Double.parsedouble("2.30") returns 2.3? and not 2.30?

Answer (score 1):

[Float.parseFloat()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29) is the problem  as it returns a **new** `float`.

> **Returns a new float initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Float.**

You are formatting just for the purpose of display . It doesn't mean the `float` will be represented by the same format internally .

You can use [java.lang.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

I am not sure why are you using `parseFloat()` twice. If you want to display the `float` in a certain format then just format it and display it.

```
Float litersOfPetrol=Float.parseFloat(stringLitersOfPetrol);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println("liters of petrol before putting in editor"+df.format(litersOfPetrol));
```