# How can Java round-trip String -> float -> String even for (some) values not representable as a float?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, numbers, type-conversion

As explained in many places (such as [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)), not all decimal fractions can be represented as floating point values (such as stored in a `float` in Java).

The typical example given is "0.2". According to this nifty [IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), the `float` closest to 0.2 is approximately 0.20000000298023224 , so parsing "0.2" as a `float` should yield this result.

However, I noted that Java seems to be able to do the impossible:

```
String number="0.2";
float f = Float.parseFloat(number);
System.out.println("Result of roundtrip String -> float -> String: "+f);
```

prints:

> Result of roundtrip String -> float -> String: 0.2

[Test on IDeone.com](http://ideone.com/qsLb21)

How does Java know that I wanted the (rounded) output "0.2", instead of the precise output "0.20000000298023224" as explained above?

The [Javadocs of `Float.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-) try to explain this:

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a?
>   There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and
>   beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to
>   uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type
>   float.

Unfortunately, this confuses me even more. Why does "printing as many digits as needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value" allow Java to print "0.2"?

Ideally, the answer would also explain *why* this printing algorithm was chosen. It is to make (some) round-trips work, as in this example? Is there another motivation?

Comment: Where is Jon Skeet when you need him? Did he BREXIT?

Comment: You know that even entering 0.21 or 0.2000001 or anything similar also returns 0.2?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464675/convert-string-to-decimal-number-with-2-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: There are 7 zeroes, 10^7 = 2^23 so probably the 3 byte mantissa of a 4 byte float is reached. So here it might still be regular. It is more often C and C++ that cheat a bit to have nicer results (my impression).

Comment: Java assumes you want the shortest string that round-trips, which is generally a good assumption. But beware -- it doesn't always return the shortest string ( http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-doesnt-print-the-shortest-strings-that-round-trip/ )

Answer (score 2):

The rounding of the output is not because of some printing algorithm. It is because of the size of `float`. If you do:

```
String fs = "0.2";
double f = Float.parseFloat(fs);
System.out.println(f);
```

You get:

> 0.20000000298023224

[Test on Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/sjWAZS)

This clearly shows that the String "0.2" is parsed as 0.20000000298023224, but the float data-type is not able to hold it, and rounds it up to 0.2. `double` data type is capable of holding this data, and hence, when you **parse it as float**, but **store it in a double**, you get the expected output.

Comment: When I parsed it as double, it still resulted in 0.2

Comment: No. On my IDE It is this. Wait, I'll try it online to show you.

Comment: @4castle See this: http://ideone.com/sjWAZS

Comment: @4castle Note that you have to **parse it as float**, but **store it in a double**

Comment: Try using `Double.parseDouble`

Comment: @4castle That will give 0.2, but the OP says that the nearest float to 0.2 is 0.20000000298023224, and hence I parsed it as a float.

Answer (score 1):

I guess 0.2 belongs to the "[Value Set Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.13)".

Comment: Hm, I think that is a different (though related) area. Value Set Conversions seem to apply to intermediate results in FP calculations, not to conversions.

Comment: Look at §5.2 of the same page.